# A number can be express in 2 to the power n or not ? How this logic work?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bit-manipulation

As we know that to check a number can be express in power of 2 or not. To solve this problem we use bit manipulation that make it fast..

```
if( n && !(n&(n-1)))
print("yes number can be express 2 to power");
print("No number can not be express 2 to power");
```

**My question is How it works. Why n&(n-1)? Why not n&(n-2) or any thing else.**

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @xenteros yes it does not work for n=1 but it can be express in 2 the power n as we know that Math.pow(2,0)=1

Comment: @xenteros yes Sir I should restrict for n=1. Thanks

Comment: @user5956891 This is incorrect. It works fine for `n=1`. However, it gets it wrong for `n=0` as described in the answer linked to above. You could add a simple check `if(!(n&(n-1)) && n)` where the `&& n` is checked for all true cases and returns True only when `n` is non-zero.

Comment: @Jedi I think there should be (n && !(n & (n - 1))) instead of (!(n&(n-1)) in my question as you suggested . I checked with counter cases ,your logic is right if n is non-zero Thanks

Comment: Remember, the order matters @user5956891. The edit you've made is more efficient than the comment above. If you first check if `n==0` you are performing an extra check most times. A better ordering is to do the `n==0` only for powers-of-two (and zero).

Comment: @Jedi Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared to the bit pattern of `n`, in `n-1` all the bits right of and including the last `1` will be flipped. The bits to the left are unchanged. For example

```
n   01001000
n-1 01000111
```

So if there is more than one `1` in the bit pattern of `n` the expression `n&(n-1)` will be non-zero.

A special case is the value 0, which is not a power of two but the expression gives 0. So it does not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This can be understood by looking at the bit representation of numbers of the form 2^n. They will be of the form 10000....000 i.e. one '1' followed by n-1 zeros. And 2^n-1 would be 01111...111 i.e. one '0' followed by n-1 ones. When you take a bitwise AND of these numbers (1000....0000 and 01111....111) you get a zero.

Comment: nice explanation Thanks .Yes you are right that 2^n=10000...000 and (2^n)-1 is 01111....111.  Does it work in case of 1 where 1 is also 2 the power n where n=0.?

Comment: @user5956891 No it does not, as explained by Henry in his answer.